# Implicit conversion between integral data types and strings in Transact-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

While dealing with a bug, I've noticed that SQL Server 2000 performs implicit conversion between integral data types and strings, even without a warning. Thus, the following query:

```
SELECT LEFT(123456789, '3')
```

returns the string `123`.

Is this a bug (feature) in SQL Server 2000? A feature of T-SQL? Or a feature of SQL itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs for `LEFT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) state

> character_expression
>
> Is an expression of character or
>   binary data. character_expression can be a constant, variable, or
>   column. **character_expression can be of any data type, except text or
>   ntext, that can be implicitly converted to varchar or nvarchar**.
>   Otherwise, use the CAST function to explicitly convert
>   character_expression.
>
> integer_expression
>
> Is a positive integer that specifies
>   how many characters of the character_expression will be returned.

The [Data Type Conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx) page of the docs clearly shows which pairs types can be implicitly converted between. Conversions between `int` and `varchar` are implicit in both directions.

So we're talking feature, not bug; and I'd say T-SQL rather than SQL, because I'd guess that the standard doesn't talk about such things. But that is just a guess.

Comment: You're true. Thank you for your answer, and please excuse my laziness on reviewing the documentation.